# Solidity Payable functions how does it work?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

```
    function buy(uint256 id) public payable returns(uint256) {
        require(msg.value >= listPrice[id], "Insufficient Bid");
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(uint256,address)", id, msg.sender);
        
        (bool success,) = address(diceContract).delegatecall(payload);
        require(success, "Transfer failed");

        diceMarket.transfer(msg.value);

        if (msg.value > listPrice[id]) {
            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value - listPrice[id]);
        }

        return listPrice[id];
    }
```

Hi, i have a DiceMarket contract function called `buy` where it checks the msg.value sufficiency and if it exceeds the ask price it should return the msg.sender some change. I'm new to solidity so i would like to ask the following:

I am confused about whether declaring it as a payable is sufficient?
or do i need to call a transfer method ?

something like payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value) ? How does it work under the hood? the end user that calls this contract's method should be from the web3 platform. He intends to buy a "dice" from this DiceMarket Contract and he needs to send some money over by calling this function.

Thanks in advance please point me to the reference that I need to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding extra complexity. you should define a function to get the price of dice

Since you have a marketplace that means you are showing the items to the user and user sees the price. so when user clicks to buy the item, you capture this value and pass it as `msg.value`. you most likely show the item in `ether`. so convert it to wei

```
 const value = web3.utils.toWei(String(dice.price));
```

when you call the buy function, you should pass it as value

```
 const result = await contract.methods
    .buy(id)
    .send({ from: account, value });
```

Since you are passing value like this, your function has to be `payable`

this way you are always sending the exact amount, so you do need to transfer anything.

- Another approach would be to pass the "price" as an argument to the `buy(id,price)`. you still capture the price and instead of   `.send({ from: account, value })`, you just add the arg to the `buy`

In this case, since you are sending price as an argument, inside `buy` you do not need to reach `msg.value` you do not need to set the function as `payable`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry as mentioned i am really noob at Solidity.

What i wanted to ask was if anyone were to sent a value across some ether i would't have to do a transfer call that would sent ethers from the sender to the contract address as it would already have been sent. (Now that i realized it, it is probably because in the distributed network the transaction was sent from the sender into the network and i've been thinking of it as requiring it to handle it like a server, which was wrong).

I did this through and could only understand it through including a function that would call address(this).balance.

Having said that the above example is accurate. Thank you @Yilmaz